# Add Group of Persons to ABAddressBookRef, group added ok, but person didn't add to Group?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have some lines of Objective-C code like:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"My Group", &error);

ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty,@"Huy 1111111",&error);
ABRecordSetValue(person,kABPersonLastNameProperty,@"AseDra",&error);
ABGroupAddMember(group, person, &error);

ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &error);

ABAddressBookSave(addressBook,&error);
```

It run fine, no error,  group added to Simulator Address Book but person didn't add to Simunator Address Book. Anybody can tell me where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Address Book Programming Guide for iOS (link below), the person record must exist in the address book before you can add them to a group.

"Before a person record can be added to a group, it must already be saved to the Address Book database."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/500-DirectInteraction/DirectInteraction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW4

So maybe this would work

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty,@"Huy 1111111",&error);
ABRecordSetValue(person,kABPersonLastNameProperty,@"AseDra",&error);

// add the person record
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, &error);

ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"My Group", &error);
ABGroupAddMember(group, person, &error);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &error);

ABAddressBookSave(addressBook,&error);
```

Comment: This took a while to figure out. Thanks for the pointers and documentation reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've read answers where you have to save the person to the address book first, then create the group and then add the person to the group, then save again.

This did not work for me.

What eventually worked for me is this:

Save the contact in the address book, save the group in the address book, add the contact to the group, and then save. Very annoying, but glad it works, and hope it works for you.

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
    bool wantToSaveChanges = YES;
    bool didSave;
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;

    addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    // If you get some error when trying to add a contact, make sure it's not a permission issue

//    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
//        
//    });

    // create person

    ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate();
    CFErrorRef anError = NULL;
    bool didSet;

    didSet = ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, CFSTR("Lily"), &anError);
    if (!didSet) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", anError); }

    didSet = ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty, CFSTR("Bell"), &anError);
    if (!didSet) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", anError); }

    bool didAdd;

    didAdd = ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, aRecord, &anError);
    if (!didAdd) { NSLog(@"Error: Couldn't add record, %@", anError); };

    // we've added the person to the address book at this point
    // now try creating a group, and adding that person to the group (failed to add, error is NULL, for whatever reason)

    // if that fails, we might need to save the added contact, then add them to the group, then save (FAILED)
    // if the above fails, save the added contact, save the group, add the contact to group, then save (PASSED)
    // if the above fails, god help us

    // saving the added person first before adding them to the group
    didSave = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
    if (!didSave) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); }


    ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate(); // create the group
    didSet = ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty, @"NYC", &anError);
    if (!didSet) { NSLog(@"Error: Couldn't set group, %@", anError); }

    didAdd = ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &anError);
    if (!didAdd) { NSLog(@"Error: Couldn't add group, %@", anError); }


    // save the group now
    didSave = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
    if (!didSave) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); }

    // adding person to group
    didAdd = ABGroupAddMember(group, aRecord, &anError);
    if (!didAdd) { NSLog(@"Error: Couldn't add contact to group, %@", anError); }

    // final save
    didSave = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
    if (!didSave) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
    CFRelease(aRecord);
    CFRelease(firstName);
    CFRelease(lastName);
```