# Unable to add contacts into specific group in iphone using ABGroupAddMember

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

I am trying to add selected contacts into specific group but contacts cant added in group.
I want to create new group and add contacts into that group. but after creating group in that group unable to add contacts.here is my code for create new group and add contacts into group:

```
    addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &err);
    group = ABGroupCreate();
    ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty, txtGroupNameText.text, &err);
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, group, &err);
    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &err);
    groupId = ABRecordGetRecordID(group);
```

and for adding contacts :

```
        ABRecordRef person = [contactArray objectAtIndex:i];
        ABRecordRef HiByeGroup = ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID(addressBook,       self.groupId);
        BOOL didAdd = ABGroupAddMember(HiByeGroup,person,&err);

        if (didAdd) {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error while adding person to HiBye group");
        }

        BOOL didSave = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &err);

        if (didSave) {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error while saving address book");
        }
```

contacts get save but not getting add.Please help me ,Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to save the Person to the address book before adding it to the group.

for example try this code , it works well

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFErrorRef error;
ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"new group", &error);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(ab, group, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);
//Create new person and save to this group
ABRecordRef record = ABPersonCreate();
BOOL isSuccess ;

isSuccess  = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonNicknameProperty,@"GroupMember nick name", &error);
isSuccess = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty, @"Middle name", &error);

ABMutableMultiValueRef copyOfPhones = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);

CFTypeRef phone= CFSTR("123000222111");

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(copyOfPhones, phone,kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel,NULL);

isSuccess = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty, copyOfPhones, &error);

isSuccess = ABAddressBookAddRecord(ab, record, &error);
isSuccess = ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);

ABGroupAddMember(group, record, &error);

NSLog(@"is success %d", isSuccess);

ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);
CFRelease(group);
```

Comment: Thanks,Its works fine but I have one mutable array of all contacts and  selected contact from that array I am trying to add into group,How can I do this? because my application is crashing ABRecordRef person = [contactArray objectAtIndex:i]; on this line.